# Can I use a rosettes iron as a branding iron?

Tags: decorating

Is it possible to use a rosettes iron as a branding iron to stamp decorations on cheesecake and bread?

[image: Rosettes]
[Rosettes](http://www.gratefulprayerthankfulheart.com/2015/04/scandinavian-rosettes.html)

[Food branding iron](http://yufentai.pixnet.net/blog/post/368200367-%E7%86%8A%E7%88%AA%E7%83%99%E5%8D%B0%E6%A8%A1%26%E8%8A%8B%E6%B3%A5%E5%90%90%E5%8F%B8)